# Rendering html to canvas

Tags: javascript, html, plugins, html2canvas, rasterize

I want to render my html to Canvas, with JS, html5;
I tried '[RasterizeHTML](http://cburgmer.github.io/rasterizeHTML.js/)' and '[html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/)' plugins but both have a lot of bugs.
Images are previewed cropped; some texts are not previewed at all.

in similar pages the same plugin behaves itself differently.

And there is a BIG issue concerning cross-browser support.

Can you tell me how to modify them or do you know the better solutions?